# Binding Combobox inside DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid with 3 column inside: Name -DataGridTextColumn, Value-DataGridTextColumn, ParamJson - DataGridTemplateColumn with combobox and has a ICollectionView of ParameterGrid as a source.

There is a ViewModel that provides ICollectionView of ParameterGrid. ParameterGrid contains 4 parameters: Name, Value, ParamJson, SelectedParamJson.

I need to handle all rows of DataGrid, so i use the command that get all dataGrid as a Command Parameter and than iterate over DataGrid.Items (I could use directly ICollectionView?).

The question is How to bind properly SelectedItem in Combobox in DataGrid to SelectedParamJson?

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="parametersGridView"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PropertiesGrid}"
                Margin="5"
                AlternatingRowBackground="LightGoldenrodYellow">

         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parameter" >
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox MinWidth="100"
                               MaxWidth="150"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParamsJson}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                               StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                               IsEditable="True">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                     </ComboBox>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

         </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid >     <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="parametersGridView"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PropertiesGrid}"
                Margin="5"
                AlternatingRowBackground="LightGoldenrodYellow">

         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parameter" >
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParamsJson}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                               StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                               IsEditable="True">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                     </ComboBox>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

         </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid >`
```

> ViewModel

```
class DataGridViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public DataGridViewModel()
    {
        var data = new DataEmulator();
        PropertiesGrid = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data.GetCommonParameters());
    }

    public ICollectionView PropertiesGrid
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(PropertiesGridProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertiesGridProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertiesGridProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PropertiesGrid", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(DataGridViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand
            {
                ExecuteAction = a =>
                {

                    // here SelectedParamJson should be as Selected in combobox,
                    // but it is always null because of the wrong binding
                },
                CanExecutePredicate = p =>
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ParameterGrid
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<SamResult> ParamsJson { get; set; }
    public SamResult SelectedParamJson { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to the `SelectedParamJson` property that is defined in the same class as the `ParamsJson` property, you should not set the `RelativeSource` property to anything at all:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParamsJson}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson}"
```

You should also move the `ComboBox` to the `CellEditingTemplate` of the `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you have to define `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>`, where you should do all bindings and `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`, that present value when the cell is not active.

That seems to be strange that you could not bind everything inside `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`, because you have to do an additional klick to activate combobox.

Xaml that works for me:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parameter" >

       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson}" />
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ComboBox MinWidth="100"
                       MaxWidth="150"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParamsJson}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson}"
                       StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                       IsEditable="True">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                   </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
             </ComboBox>
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I will be appreciate for another solution where ComboBox work without additional click on the cell to activate it

Comment: Dear @mm8 if I understand correctly your answer was `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParamsJson}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson}"`, but if you take a glance at my answer the problem was in another thing. In my question I defined `Combobox` in `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>` section  instead of `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>`. And for some reason binding _does not work_ when `Combobox` defined in `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`. In my variant you don't see `Combobox` before clicking on cell. Please publish your answer with full code if it works.

Comment: You are using  `RelativeSource` in your original code. That's why the *binding* doesn't work. Anyway, I updated my answer to include a note about putting the element in the `CellEditingColumn`.

Comment: ok, lets merge our answers in you post. And please mark my answer as useful back.

Answer (score 0):

your ancestor is not the datagrid its the datarow you want to get the datacontext from.

so you made a collection view of some source collection like list, this means every row in your Datagrid repesents a IJsonObject Object and there you should have your Collection for the ComboBox Column defined. Like a List that you can bind to the Column and in Turn you can have a IJsonProperty field that you can bind to the selected Item.

So then you should get a Combobox filled with yout List Items and if you select one of them the IJsonProerty Field will be set to the selected Item.

I hope its understandable since I dont really got a code snippet right now.

Comment: unfortunately `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParamJson, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"` does not work for me

Comment: well if there isnt a property called SelectedParamJson on the object that is bound to the datagrid row it cant work. So you need to bind to something that is exposed by the object or if you got a more global Property then you might need to find an ancestor like usercontrol or window. again relative source is looking up public proerties in the acestors datacontext, so you need to figure out where SelectedParamJson is defined and which control has the vm it is defined in.

Comment: there is DataGrid that has `ItemsSource="{Binding PropertiesGrid}"`. I believed that Combobx inside DataGridTemplateColumn shoul see SelectedParamJson directly, without any AncestorType ...

Comment: if your data is a collection of ParameterGrid objects then every is a ParameterGrid which in Turn can expose is public properies as Datagrid Cell Bindings (your Column definistions) so if you bind to an Ancestor that is a DataGridRow there should be a public Property called SelectedParamJson that can be bound to SelectedItem Property of the Combobox. So your ComboBox Itemsource is ParamsJson and your selected Item is SelectedParamJson

Comment: and yes if you already in the context you dont need a lookup of an ancestor because the SelectedParamJson sould be in the same scope